# Optical zoom in ScrollViewer having odd panning behavior

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm building a picture viewing app. In it I have a FlipView that shows individual images, where you can optical zoom each image. The experience is very similar to the FlipView/Optical zoom you see in the default Photos app in windows 8 (which is built using html).

I'm using a ScrollViewer for optical zoom. Optical zoom seems to be working fine except there is an odd panning behavior. You can still use a single finger to pan the image around, before it goes back to it's original position.

The photos app doesn't allow this, and I'm trying to achieve a similar behavior. Is there some way to disable panning the image around using the built in ScrollViewer control? I still want zooming in to work, but panning should be disabled. I think this should be achievable using manipulation events instead of ScrollViewer, but obviously ScrollViewer would be simpler.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer1" ZoomMode="Enabled" MaxZoomFactor="2.0" MinZoomFactor="1.0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <FlipView x:Name="flipView1" Width="1140" SelectionChanged="flipView1_SelectionChanged">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Image x:Name="CurrentImage" Source="{Binding}" DoubleTapped="CurrentImage_DoubleTapped">                                
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
    </ScrollViewer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the FlipView to ScrollView since you must add the scrollview to flipview item template, and the image must be inside the scrollview, your xaml code must be like this:

```
<FlipView x:Name="flipView1" Width="1140" SelectionChanged="flipView1_SelectionChanged">
            <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                       <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer1" ZoomMode="Enabled" MaxZoomFactor="2.0" MinZoomFactor="1.0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image x:Name="CurrentImage" Source="{Binding}" DoubleTapped="CurrentImage_DoubleTapped">                                
                        </Image>
                      </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        </FlipView>
```

Comment: **Totally!** Additionally I've added the content of <DataTemplate> to a UserControl to be able to access the _scrollViewer1_ and used the FindName method to access it in the _flipView1_SelectionChanged_ event. Thanks!